# What is the rolling compounded annual ROI if you start off using .000457% ($4.57) of $10,000 over 1,095 trades?

Tags: percentages

What is the rolling compounded annual ROI if you start off using .000457% ($4.57) of $10,000 over $1,095$ trades?

If you use a flat 0.000457 it would be 50.04% ($5,004.15) but if you continuously use a compounded 0.000457% it will grow every day until you reach your 1,095th trade. What is the final compounded annual ROI if you take this into consideration?

Thank you

Comment: $1.000457^{1095} - 1$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you mean that on each trade you get a 0.000457 additionally from the amount invested and that you invest the initial 10000$ plus all the benefits acquired before on all future trades.

So basically after 1 trade you have:

$$
A_1=10000(1+0.000457)=10004.57$
$$

After the second trade you have:

$$
A_2=(1+0.000457)(1+0.000457)10000=10009.14$
$$

then at the n-th trade you will have:

$$
A_n=(1+0.000457)^n10000
$$

and your ROI will be $(1+0.000457)^n$. So after 1095 trades, plug in $n=1095$ to get:

$$
ROI_{1095}=(1+0.000457)^{1095}=1.65
$$

and a final account of $ROI_{1095}10000=16492.17$ for a benefit of 6492.17$ from your initial investment.